# use npm mqtt package in my angular projecct

Tags: angularjs, npm, mqtt

How can I use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#connect
in my angular project? It is not a regular angular package so what should I load in the module and in the controller to make it work?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use mqtt.js yet but i think that link will help you a bit to understand the integration of mqtt with angular. [angular-MQTT](https://github.com/shellus/angular-MQTT)